# Linux command line to create a log file for rsync

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, rsync

I am trying to create a log text file after doing an rsync. I've tried using a command line:

```bsh
rsync -av /source/ /dest/ > log.txt
```

The text file that was created only shows the file names that are "different" between the source folder & the destination folder, which is close to what I want.

Is there a way for me to create a log file that groups the files that are "different" into files that were modified & created?

Answer (score 24):

Use the `--log-file` option. See `man rsync` for details. Example usage:

```bash
rsync -av /source/ /dest/ --log-file=mylog.log
```

Note that successive runs will *append* to the log file, rather than overwriting it. Also, rsync logs *both* stderr and stdout type information to the specified log file.

Answer (score 12):

**The main idea**
For any *modern* `rsync` it's possible to use `--info` instead of `-v`, e.g:

```
rsync --info=COPY2,DEL2,NAME2,BACKUP2,REMOVE2,SKIP2 -a source/ dest/ > log.txt
# or eventually with --log-file=mylog.txt
```

---

**Some additional operations**

The resulting output/file will be similar to

```
file1.zip is uptodate
file2.odt
Dir1/
Dir1/file3.txt
```

Then you can use `grep` to filter the results, for example with something like

```
grep    'is uptodate' mylog.txt | sed 's/is uptodate//g' > Already_Uptodate.txt
grep -v 'is uptodate' mylog.txt                          > Updated_Now.txt
```

<sup>In the first line I deleted the string 'is uptodate' with sed to have a more clean output. This open the problem if you have a file named '*is uptodate*' of course :-) It has to be handled in a different way...</sup>

---

**Some words more**

You can select the info and the *info level* that you desire for each single option

> In a *modern* `rsync`, the `-v` option is equivalent to the setting of groups of --info and --debug options.
>
> **You can choose to use these newer options**  in addition to, or **in place of using `--verbose`, as any fine-grained settings** override the implied settings of `-v`.
>
> Both `--info` and `--debug` have a way to ask for help that tells you exactly what flags are set for each increase in verbosity.

The list obtained with `rsync --info=help` is reported below meanwhile the one from `rsync --debug=help` is not reported at all:

```
Use OPT or OPT1 for level 1 output, OPT2 for level 2, etc.; OPT0 silences.  

BACKUP     Mention files backed up
COPY       Mention files copied locally on the receiving side
DEL        Mention deletions on the receiving side
FLIST      Mention file-list receiving/sending (levels 1-2)
MISC       Mention miscellaneous information (levels 1-2)
MOUNT      Mention mounts that were found or skipped
NAME       Mention 1) updated file/dir names, 2) unchanged names
PROGRESS   Mention 1) per-file progress or 2) total transfer progress
REMOVE     Mention files removed on the sending side
SKIP       Mention files that are skipped due to options used
STATS      Mention statistics at end of run (levels 1-3)
SYMSAFE    Mention symlinks that are unsafe

ALL        Set all --info options (e.g. all4)
NONE       Silence all --info options (same as all0)
HELP       Output this help message

 Options added for each increase in verbose level:
1) COPY,DEL,FLIST,MISC,NAME,STATS,SYMSAFE
2) BACKUP,MISC2,MOUNT,NAME2,REMOVE,SKIP
```

In case on of the rsync (client-server) is not enough *modern* you have to use more `v` and more effort. Indeed you can use `-vv`, `-vvv`, `-vvvv` increasing each time in verbosity, but the parsing will be more complex.

> More than two -v options should only be used if you are debugging rsync

A really useful lecture might be `man rsync` in the section where it speaks about the options `-v` and especially `--info=FLAGS`.